# regex expression to allow user type any symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, input-mask

I'm using react-maskedinput and for mask it accept regular expression . I'm getting mask  from backend . Sometimes mask is empty and I need to set default mask. If it's empty I want to allow user type any 40 symbols.

```
export function getMaskForInput(mask) {
  const newMask = mask.toString().replace(/`9/g, 'q').replace(/9/g, '1').replace(/q/g, '`9');
  const emptyMask = '/\W{40}/g';  // probably not correct expression
  if (mask) {
    return newMask.replace(/`/g, '\\').replace('$', '');
  }
  console.log('empty mask');

  return emptyMask;
}

const mask = getMaskForInput(maskEdit)

<MaskedInput
  mask={mask}
  type="tel"
  id="account"
  autoComplete="off"
  maxLength={40}
  placeholder="№ лицевого счета"
  placeholderChar=" "
  onChange={(e) => this.handleOnAccountChange(e.target.value.trim())}
  value={this.state.account}
  formatCharacters={{
     W: {
     validate(char) { return /[\wа-яА-Я \-0-9.@]/.test(char); },
     },
     w: {
     validate(char) { return /[\wа-яА-Я \-0-9.@]/.test(char); },
     }
}}
/>
```

But when I return 'emptyMask'  it shows my actual regex for mask . Where I'm making mistake?

[image]

Comment: `'/\W{40}/g'` is a string literal containing a regex literal, it is wrong. You need `/\W{40}/g`, without quotes, if you need to set a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried without quotes, I get an error " Failed prop type: Invalid prop `mask` of type `regexp` supplied to `MaskedInput`, expected `string`."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the `MaskedInput` component works.

`MaskedInput`'s mask format string is *not a regular expression*. It's a user-friendly *string*. You can use strings like `"11-11"` which would be equivalent to the regular expression `/^\d\d-\d\d$/`.

This format string has some [characters you can use out of the box](https://github.com/insin/inputmask-core#pattern) — `1`, `a`, `A`, `*` and `#` represent classes of characters (eg: `1` represents any digit), and symbols (such as `-` or `/` represent themselves).

You can define your own symbol classes, which is what you're doing with `w` and `W` — you're defining those classes as anything that matches the regular expression `[\wа-яА-Я \-0-9.@]`.

However to mask 40× your custom character class, you can't use `W{40}` because `{40}` is valid for a regex but not for the mask string. Remember that mask is not a regular expression. So if you want a mask that matches 40× the `W` class, you need to use `"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"`, or `"W".repeat(40)`.